Why did the Vorlons miss with their first shot?
Near the end of the episode Deathwalker, when the Vorlon cruiser emerges from hyperspace and attacks Jhad'ur's flyer, the first beam they fire misses yet the second one destroys the ship.
Are we to assume the first shot was a misfire or did the episode writer have a reason for the first beam going wide?

If there was meaning around them missing with the first shot, it would probably be mentioned here: http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/countries/us/guide/009.html in the "JMS Speaks" section. The fact that he states that the Vorlon ship "couldn't miss" suggests it's probably just there to liven up the special effects a little.

Maybe the Vorlon wanted Deathwalker to see death approaching.  If they killed her with the first shot, she'd have no time to feel fear or futility or OH SHI!

@gowenfawr- these are vorlons we're talking about, do you really think they'd care if she died in fear?

A storm trooper was manning the weapons controls for the first shot.
